# Set an inactive object active again after from Main Menu to gameplay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an inventory system in my game that is set active on button press.  I made the inventory system's game objects DontDestroyOnLoad when switching between scenes. When the player returns to the main menu the game objects are set inactive. I don't know how to set them active again when returning to the game.

Here's how I made them inactive when going to the main menu:

```
if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("MainMenu"))
{
    backpack.SetActive(false);
    buttonI.SetActive(false);
    backpackAudio.Stop();
    canvas.SetActive(false);
    InventoryManager.SetActive(false);
}
else
{
    // Something here
}
```

I tried to set them active when getting the current scene again but it won't work. I thought about PlayerPrefs because I already have a Save&Load system, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: use a scriptable object to manage state